# Why is MS word mis ordering my bibliography

Tags: microsoft-word, bibliography

I was forced into creating a document with MS Word, and had to deal with its bibliography handling.  I downloaded different styles (because they had nothing useful) and I am using IEEE Reference order.  The numbered ordering is correct in the text (that is done in the order they appear).  But in the bibliography list the order is basically random 1,5,2,3,4,7,6,8,9.

The are not done alphabetically, chronologically, or any other way that might make sense.  Guessing, they are listed in the order in which they were entered when I added them to the document after it was written.  Is there anyway to undo this and have it do something intelligent short of deleting it entirely and rewriting it manually

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are using the Inset Citation, Manage Sources and Bibliography functions, which tend to work really well.

In Word 2003, my APA formated bibliographies are alphabetic, and selecting IEEE 2006 makes them numbered in order of place in document.

A [custom style](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj851016.aspx) could result in unexpected behaviour such as you are seeing. On the other hand, [downloading new custom styles](https://bibword.codeplex.com/) could fix your problem.

Or use a non-IEEE style for now and have alphabetic references.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to reproduce something similar to the problem you described.

I entered a name (Government of South Australia) in the publisher field for a piece of legislation, and left author blank. I then changed my mind, and moved the name from publisher to author. Then I decided that it should be a corporate author, to stop the name from being reordered as 'Australia, Government of South'.

After all these changes, this reference was appearing in first position, rather than under "G".

In "Manage Sources" the Preview gave the citation as ( Gov...) with a space before the name that shouldn't have been there.

Editing the source and unticking and then reticking the corporate author check box fixed the issue, and now the source plots under "G" rather than at the start of the list.